# How to prevent programs like Jenkins from stopping/sleeping/waiting

Tags: process

I know this is probably a silly question, but I'm trying to get Jenkins running on my pi for a project.

I've installed jenkins, changed the port to 9080 and port forwarded so that I can view it anywhere. And this works but only for 5 or so minutes, before the port is closed. Before those 5 minutes I can access it from another network, but after leaving the pi inactive it stops. Just by going back onto the Pi and refreshing the page and doing stuff will jenkins open up on the port again.

This also happened on my Ubuntu VM, so I'm guessing it's a linux thing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `This also happened on my Ubuntu VM, so I'm guessing it's a linux thing. ` so it's off-topic here...

Comment: But to give you a starting point: I would first check if it works in the local network, without port forwarding. It may be a problem with your router for example

Comment: @dirk Sorry I'll post to linux stack exchange once I'm able to. The problem is when I check locally, ie., go to localhost:9080 the program starts working again for all networks. Maybe it is a router thing but my Minecraft server runs on port 25565 on Windows 24/7 and never needs rebooting